# Is there a way to calculate Euclidean distance of two vectors by KMeans(BigQueryML)?

Tags: sql, vector, k-means, euclidean-distance, bigml

Given a table or dataset that holds data for two fields namely V_1 and V_2 and Use Euclidean distance as the distance type to measure distance between the given vectors

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHEvm.png)

```
+-------------+------------+
| V_1         |   V_2      |
+-------------+------------+
| 0.000002    | 0.001652   |
| 0.001652    | V0.000007  |
| 0.000007    | 0.000065   |
| 0.000065    | 0.000003   |
| 0.000003    | 0.001489   |
+-------------+------------+
```

Also need to create a random sampling with 75% of the record that is available in the given file as training set and remaining 25% as the test set.

I tried to find euclidean distance by the following sql query

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(SQRT(POW(MIN(V_1) - MAX(V_2),2) + POW(MIN(V_2) - MAX(V_1),2)),4)
FROM
   Training.training dataset
```

As I am new to BigML query not sure on how to get a random sampling as suggested.

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: instead of the training set, you order the origina, data by RAND() and use the first 75% of the rows as base for your query

Comment: can you explain me this in detail?

Comment: look for CTE, the you make a SELECT with ORDER BY rand() you need the count(*) from all rows to get the number 75 procent of te rows. there you haev all yyou need so give it a try